# Using web3.py, I get a key error when connecting to a remote server with 3 nodes running (autoconnect works fine)

Tags: web3.py, python, web3-providers

I have a `web3.py` project that is successfully performing basic tasks (read from blockchain, send tx, process data, etc.). It is connected to a remote server that is running an ETH node, a Rinkeby node, and an ETC node. The project works perfectly using the `web3.py` auto detection.

When I switch to `Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545"))`, I am having an issue *only* when I try to send a transaction. I can use this `HTTPProvider` and still read all the correct data, such as addresses, balances, nonce, etc. The only thing I error out on is when I run `sendTranscation()`. The error I am receiving is:

`{'code': -32000, 'message': 'no key for given address or file'}`

I assume this has something do with my key, but I cannot imagine what. The directory in my server is completely normal (`~/.ethereum/keystore`, `~/.ethereum/testnet/keystore`, and `~/ethereum-classic/keystore`). This doesn't totally make sense, though, because I can still read the nonce.

I am connecting to the server via SSH and the `~/.ssh/config` file.

Do I need to point my connection to the correct keystore location? If so where in the stack do I do this?

Comment: The error is saying that the node you connected to doesn't have the private key for the address you want to send from. So it appears you are connecting to a different node than you thought (or don't have the private key imported). What happens if you use `from web3.auto.http import w3`? The automatic connection could be connecting to an unexpected node over IPC.

Comment: @carver that seems to work. What exactly does adding the `http` do? And if I want to connect to a different port, how do I do that?

Comment: It works, as in you can send transactions? I would expect the `web3.auto.http` to work exactly the same as `Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('http://localhost:8545'))`. Unless you have the `WEB3_HTTP_PROVIDER_URI` environment variable set.